# Does this prove the validity of this First Order Logic formula?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic

Is this a valid proof for the following problem?

Prove:

$$\models (\exists x : A(x) \to \forall x : B(x)) \to \forall x : (A(x) \to B(x))$$

Proof by contradiction:

1. Assume $(\exists x: A(x) \to \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot (\forall x(A(x) \to B(x))$
2. $ (\lnot \exists x : A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot\forall x : (A(x) \to B(x))$  logical equivalence
3. $\forall x : \lnot A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot(\forall x : (A(x) \to B(x))$  logical equivalence
4. $\lnot A(a) \lor B(a) \land \lnot((A(a) \to B(a))$          instantiation
5. $((A(a) \to B(a)) \land \lnot((A(a) \to B(a))$          a contradiction

$\therefore (\exists x: A(x) \to \forall x : B(x)) \to \forall x(A(x) \to B(x))$

Edit: corrected a typo on step 2

Update: Professor's Solution:

1. Assume $(\exists x: A(x) \to \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot (\forall x(A(x) \to B(x))$
2. $ (\lnot \exists x : A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot\forall x : (A(x) \to B(x))$  logical equivalence
3. $ (\lnot \exists x : A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot\forall x : (\lnot A(x) \lor B(x))$  logical equivalence
4. $ ( \forall x : \lnot A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \lnot\forall x : (\lnot A(x) \lor B(x))$  logical equivalence
5. $ ( \forall x : \lnot A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \exists x : \lnot(\lnot A(x) \lor B(x))$  logical equivalence
6. $ ( \forall x : \lnot A(x) \lor \forall x : B(x)) \land \exists x : ( A(x) \land \lnot B(x))$  distribute negation
7. $ ( \lnot A(a) \lor B(a)) \land ( A(a) \land \lnot B(a))$  instantiation
8. $ ( \lnot A(a) \lor B(a)) \land ( \lnot A(a) \lor B(a))$  logical equivalence, resulting in a contradiction

$\therefore (\exists x: A(x) \to \forall x : B(x)) \to \forall x(A(x) \to B(x))$

What I learned: it is typically safe to instantiate when there is one existential quantifier, which is not negated.

Comment: Why on Earth is this downvoted? Sure, the user didn't use $\LaTeX$, but come on! They're new!

Comment: Please use MathJax is future, @OldGreg.

Comment: @Shaun: It's not my downvote, but there's a loose group of users who don't like pure proof-verification questions and think they don't add value to the site.

Comment: I am of the view that it is better to edit new contributor's work into mathjax rather then downvoting them for that.

Comment: Same. I've started the hard parts of editing the mathjax into the post, but I'm a bit strapped on time. Finishing up the mathjax edits would be good editing practice if someone else is interested.

Comment: That might explain it, then, @HenningMakholm. Thank you.

Comment: I apologize, I will make sure to properly format my questions in the future using MathJax. Is there a better place to ask proof verification questions?

Comment: @OldGreg: I am not aware of a place where such "check-my-homework" questions are _more_ accepted. You can probably attract better and more focused answers, however, if you can point to a particular place in your proof where you're not sure if it works, and explain a bit about what it is that makes you unsure.

Comment: I see, I am having trouble understanding when instantiation is allowed.

Comment: Personally I'm okay with "Check if I did my homework right' questions.  It shows that the person has made the effort to do their homework.  Its not like someone who is trying to avoid the work.

Comment: I believe you have a typo with the first parenthesis on step 2.

Comment: Also, are you attempting a formal proof (following a set of rules) or an informal proof (using your intuition) ?

Comment: @DanielV I am attempting to be as formal as possible, but I am a beginner, so any pointers would be appreciated. Also, I think you spotted a typo in my second line, I would like to correct it. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

In step 2 you make use of the equivalence

$\neg(\exists x . A(x) \lor \forall x.B(x)) \iff \forall x . \neg A(x) ∨ \forall x . B(x) $

This is not a real equivalence compare it to demorgans law.

$\neg(\exists x . A(x) \lor \forall x.B(x)) \iff \neg(\exists x . A(x)) \land \neg(\forall x.B(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 is wrong!

It looks like you instantiated all universals with an $a$, but you cannot do that when the universals are part of a larger sentence.

Consider: Suppose you have

$$\neg \forall x \ P(x) \land \neg \forall x \ \neg P(x)$$

Now, if we are allowed to just instantiate each of these universals with an $a$, we would get $\neg P(a) \land \neg \neg P(a)$, which is a contradiction. But, the orginal statement is not a contradiction at all; if we interpret $P(x)$ as '$x$ is even', and the domain is all numbers, then the original statement is obviously true.

Even more fundamentally, if you have $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$, you cannot fill in anything you want. Using the same interpretation as before, it is clear that $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$ is true, but $\neg P(0)$ is not. So, you cannot instantiate a universal with anything you wany if it is being negated, but this is what you did when in step 4 you went from $\neg \forall x (A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$ to $\neg (A(a) \rightarrow B(x))$

Step 2 is also wrong. The result of rewriting  the conditional as an implication should be:

$(\neg \exists x \ A(x) \lor \forall x \ B(x)) \land \neg \forall x (A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$

Interestingly, given *your* step 2, step 3  is also wrong, as pointed out by @QthePlatypus, but with this corrected step 2, your step 3 actually *would* follow ... so maybe this was just a typo on your part?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I am a beginner, and I am still struggling with understanding when instantiation is allowed, I don't yet have a good strategy. It looks like a strategy might be to translate the line into informal English, in order to see whether or not instantiating will lead to a contradiction.

Would a translation of your example be something like:
"No number x is both even and not even."?

If you know of any good resources, I would love more practice with quantifiers and instantiation, the more examples the better.

Comment: thanks again, I made the correction to step 2.

Comment: @oldgreg The official rule of instantiation is such that you can only use it when the *whole* statement is a universal. Any universal that is part of a larger statement cannit be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a syntactic proof for a *conditional statement*, I suggest that you should use a Conditional Proof format.

So assume $\exists x~A(x)\to\forall x~B(x)$ and do something to derive $\forall x~(A(x)\to B(x))$.

Then discharge the assumption with conditional introduction.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{1.~\exists x~A(x)~\to~\forall x~B(x)}{\fitch{~\ldots}{~\ddots}\\8.~\forall x~(A(x)\to B(x))}\\9.~(\exists x~A(x)\to\forall x~B(x))\to\forall x~(A(x)\to B(x))}$